# ASP Email - objCDOMail.Send server error

Tags: email, asp-classic, send

I have to build an email for for a basic website which has to be in ASP, which is something I know nothing about.

I have built the form and it all seems to work error free up until the point where the email has to be sent, specifically this line:

```
objCDOMail.Send
```

The error reported in the browser is:

> Server Error 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the
>   resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening?
All suggestions will be very much appreciated!

The full code is as follows:

```
<%   
Dim name, email, comments 
Dim objCDOMail 'The CDO object
name = Request.Form("name")
email = Request.Form("email")
comments = Request.Form("query")
message = "<HTML><table border='0' width='80%' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><tr><td> " & _
    "<p><strong>Name:</strong> " & name & _
    "<p><strong>E-mail:</strong> " & email & _
    "<p><strong>Comments:</strong> " & comments & _
    "<p><hr></td></tr></table></html>"
Response.Write("" & message & "<br />")
Set objCDOMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objCDOMail.From = "user@domain.co.uk"
objCDOMail.To = "user@domain.co.uk"
objCDOMail.Subject = ""
objCDOMail.HTMLBody = message
objCDOMail.Send
Set objCDOMail = Nothing    
%>
```

Comment: Are you using a valid email address for the `From` field?  Normally this wouldn't result in the error you've detailed (it just wouldn't send), but it's worth a try.  (Where's that straw gone?  Let me clutch at it!)

Comment: Why don't you enable detailed errors in IIS and your browser so you can see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably something to do with the server.  IIS6 and IIS7 deal with it in different ways. However this should help you get around it. It is code I have pulled from an existing site and altered a little. You'll have to augment to your own purposes:

```
Response.Buffer = True
Dim strBody
Dim objCDOMail
Dim strMyEmailAddress
Dim strCCEmailAddress
Dim strBCCEmailAddress
Dim strReturnEmailAddress

'THIS IS WHERE YOU CHANGE THE EMAIL ADDRESS
 strMyEmailAddress = "you@yourdomain.com"
'strBCCEmailAddress = "bcc@yourdomain.com"

strReturnEmailAddress = Request.Form("Email")
strBody = strBody & "<br /><br /><span><strong>Name:</strong></span> " & Request.Form("name")
strBody = strBody & "<br /><br /><span><strong>E-mail:</strong></span> " & Request.Form("email")
strBody = strBody & "<br /><br /><span><strong>Company:</strong></span> " & Request.Form("company")
strBody = strBody & "<br /><br /><span><strong>Enquiry:</strong></span> " & Request.Form("enquiry")
strBody = strBody & "</p></div></body>"
If Len(strReturnEmailAddress) < 5 OR NOT Instr(1, strReturnEmailAddress, " ") = 0 OR InStr(1,    strReturnEmailAddress, "@", 1) < 2 OR InStrRev(strReturnEmailAddress, ".") < InStr(1,strReturnEmailAddress, "@", 1) Then
strReturnEmailAddress = strMyEmailAddress
End If  
Set objCDOMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objCDOMail.From = Request.Form("name") & " <" & strReturnEmailAddress & ">"
objCDOMail.To = strMyEmailAddress
objCDOMail.Cc = strCCEmailAddress
objCDOMail.Bcc = strBCCEmailAddress
objCDOMail.Subject = "Your Email Subject"
objCDOMail.HTMLBody = strBody   '**This is for HTML Emails**
objCDOMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
objCDOMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="localhost"
objCDOMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25
objCDOMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objCDOMail.Send
Set objCDOMail = Nothing
```

The last few lines deal with the server and use use the localhost for sending mail. You can change this depending on your SMTP server.